# How to handle search results that point to a page of aggregated entries?

Tags: search, channels

I have a few pages in my site that aggregate information, for example, a single awards page that gets all the entries in an **awards** channel. Single **awards** entries don't have their own URLs.

How do I handle cases like this in search results?

Answer (score 1):

I guess I'll answer my own question. Use a conditional in search results and overwrite the value of the entry's URL:

```
{% if getSection() == 'mySection' %}
  {% set entry.url = '/mySectionUrl' %}
{% endif %}
```